# Rendering React components and static HTML

Tags: html, reactjs

Using ReactJS, which approach is better, having to deal with both dynamic content and static HTML:

1) Render view with one "main" component containing all other components(dynamic or static) - "one entry point".

2) Render static HTML outside React scope and use multiple "independent" components to render dynamic content - "multiple entry points".

Answer (score 1):

Having multiple entry points in our application can cause complexities if we scale our codebase. Its better to have one main component that contains all the other components (children) and renders them using the props from a store. That's why we have smart containers and dumb containers if you've used Redux.